# cant boot after opening 2nd partition on hard drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, bootloader

have ubuntu 14 and opened another partition on hard drive, i checked the box making this partition boot able and restarted computer, now can't get computer to boot any ideas how to fix? have tried booting in recovery mode have tried to boot from mem stick but no luck

Comment: tried boot repair disk still no luck I have bios set to boot off usb but computer doesn't see the usb

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the CD, run [GParted](http://gparted.org/screenshots.php) and select the 'boot' flag for the Linux partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from the [Boot-repair-disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It starts LXDE session and opens window for fixing GRUB and the whole boot process. Use `recommended repair`.